# Failing to load an angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I'm a complete angular noob so I'm following some tutorials, using Angular 1.5.8; right now, following a video about the angular-local-storage module I get this error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=toDoApp&p1=Error%3A…Orion%2FProyectos%2FAngularLearning%2FtodoList%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A179)(…)

The whole log is:

Failed to instantiate module toDoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=toDoApp
    at file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:6:412
    at file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:25:99
    at b (file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:24:142)
    at file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:24:385
    at file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:39:471
    at q (file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at cb (file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:43:336)
    at c (file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:20:390)
    at Bc (file:///C:/Users/Orion/Proyectos/AngularLearning/todoList/angular.min.js:21:179

This is my HTML:
[image: This is my HTML:]

And my angular module where I need to use the local storage module:
[image: Angular code]

I've searched for solutions to this but I haven't found it, I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your code here, not in screen shots!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `toDoApp` module is never created, because its dependencies cannot be satisfied.

Here's your `toDoApp` creation:

```
var app = angular.module('toDoApp', [LocalStorageModule]);
//                                           ^
//                                          ???
```

What's `LocalStorageModule` here? It's a variable ; most likely `undefined`!

Angular expects in that list of dependencies, the modules' **names** -- plain, simple, `String`s.
You want to use:

```
var app = angular.module('toDoApp', ['LocalStorageModule']);
//                                            ^
//                                       module name
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't notice it. Thanks :)